# jQuery-Select2: Add ability to adding own entry on list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

**Quick desc:**

I trying to add ability to adding own entry on list.
It's not even working when I left just `tags: true` nothing change.
Thanks in advance. Below is code and jsfiddle snipped.

**HTML**

```
 <input id="placeSelect">
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
 var data = new Array();
     data.push({
     id: "search-0",
     text: "Default"
 });

 $('#placeSelect').select2({
    tags: "true",
    width: '60%',
    multiple: "true",
    allowClear: "true",
    placeholder: "Enter name of city",
    data: data
 });
```

Here is the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/340hkLwc/2/)

**EDIT:**

Whole code on snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/340hkLwc/7/)

Comment: Do you want to add multiple tags in list,right?

Comment: i want to give ability to user to add own city :)

Comment: I think for this, you need to provide text box to user, when user enter city in text box, dynamically you add that city in your list. data.push({
    id: "search-0",
    text: "Default"
},{
    id: "search-1",
    text: "Default1"
},{
    id: "search-2",
    text: "Default2"
});

Comment: this link will help you https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: But this cannot be done :( this is piece of two-level combobox search ;)

Comment: I can provide whole coffeescript code if this helps :)

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/zremOV

Comment: edited question and pasted whole code. Maybe thats clarify a bit what i want do :)

Comment: @Trushna thats isn't what this shoud working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's an issue with the input tag, change it to a select instead.

[Select2 Documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#input-fallback)

> Deprecated in Select2 4.0. It is now encouraged to use the select tag instead.
>
> In past versions of Select2, a  element could only be used with a limited subset of options. An  was required instead, which did not allow for a graceful fallback for users who did not have  JavaScript enabled. Select2 now supports the  element for all options, so it is no longer required to use  elements with Select2.

Comment: after change to select nothing changed: